# I don't know whats wrong with the below cod, thrrows an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, mysql, sails.js

I don't know whats wrong with the below code, throws an error,

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment`

can some body help me, please

Code:

```
if i != 0:
    agentAttributes = etree.SubElement(root, "agentAttributes")
    agentAttribute = etree.SubElement(agentAttributes, "agentAttribute")
    attribute = etree.SubElement(agentAttribute, "attribute")
    refURL = etree.SubElement(attribute, "refURL")
    refURL.text = "/unifiedconfig/config/attribute/5007"
    name = etree.SubElement(attribute, "name")
    name.text = "CustomerService"
    attributeValue = etree.SubElement(agentAttribute, "attributeValue")
    attributeValue.text = "5"
    datatype = etree.SubElement(attribute, "datatype")
    datatype.text = "4"

    # print("After adding"+(str(etree.tostring(root))))


    r = requests.put(wsurl, verify=False, data=(etree.tostring(root)),
                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/xml"}, auth=('tsup01', 'Sp33chs0ft'))
    #       print("after put"+(r.text))
conn.close()
conn1.close()

#print("Adding one Attribute to all agents duration in hh:mm:ss  = " + str(datetime.now() - startTime))
#returnString = "Adding one Attribute to all agents duration in hh:mm:ss  = " + str(datetime.now() - startTime)
return HttpResponse(r.text)
```

Comment: could you provide the full stack trace? Also why do you have a `sails.js` tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from `r` being defined within the `if i != 0:` statement. Since you haven't provided the full function, I am assuming that you are not assigning the variable `r` before the `if` statement, meaning that when you do the `return HttpResponse(r.text)`, `r` is indeed unassigned!

To fix your problem, assign `r` outside of the `if i != 0:` statement.

Hope this helps!